# Unable to add time (h:mm:ss) in single column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

[image]I am unable to add time that I have imported in Excel from a csv. The time is in h:mm:ss format. Whenever I attempt to sum the vaules it returns zero. I tried changing the data type to general and number both and also attempted to correct with text-to-column tool with no success. What am I missing? I am open to a solution in VBA and SQL if there is one known.

Comment: It is hard to give you an accurate answer without any sample data, especially when it comes to this kind of format issue. Could you perhaps provide a screenshot?

Comment: Regarding the issue itself: what I can say with the information at hand, is that when a sum of something returns 0, and changing the format doesn't do anything, there's a good chance that the cell contains a text, even though it looks like a time. What happens if you select one of this cells, press `F2` and then `Enter`? Does Excel convert the value to an actual time?

Comment: Thank you piko. Pressing F2 and then Enter did not convert it to an actual time. I should clarify that when I say time, these units are the duration of phone calls. I will attempt to post a screenshot shortly. This is my first question so input is welcome if I am responding in the wrong place.

Comment: No worries! Format is often a problem in Excel, depending on the locale and especially when importing from other tools.

Comment: @piko I just tried to split the times using "MID" and "RIGHT" functions and was not able to add the results. I copied the values in another column and noticed it threw an error, saying the values are being stored as text. I then tried "text to column" again with no luck. It appears these are still being stored as text, despite the fact they came from another worksheet and any formatting I try to apply. Not sure what else I can do to convert it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't post an answer, but I may have found a solution, illustrated [in this screenshot](https://prdx.fr/NodGKb.jpg). Basically, values in column B have a space as the first character. You need to remove it, and convert the value to a number. You can do both by using the `TRIM()` function, and then multiplying by 1. Finally, apply a "Time" format, and you're good to go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it has been a while. I figured it out. I was able to make it work by selecting the time range, going to the Data tab and selecting "From Table/Range" from Transform data group. This opened the power query editor where I was able to change the data type to "duration" and place the data back in the original column.

Thank you @piko for the help.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure the column is formatted as a [time](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/format-numbers-as-dates-or-times-418bd3fe-0577-47c8-8caa-b4d30c528309#bm1). After that [you can `SUM()` them  together](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-or-subtract-time-16aa6697-6d6e-49c1-8e2c-3398a7cad6ad)

Comment: I think that only works sometimes.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: If the values are stored as text, which might be the reason why UpNorthData can't sum these cells, formatting as a time won't help. It needs to be converted to a time first.